# How to use C# DateTime.TryParse (easiest way possible)

Tags: c#, datetime

Im using visual studio 2012 on win7 pt-BR machine, but need this code to work on Win2003ServerR2 en-US Server too.

Getting the following errors:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal mscorlib    at
>   System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)    at
>   System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider
>   provider)    at AppCombustivel.Service1.TabelaConsumos()
>   System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String,
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo,
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles)

My ShortDate Server Config:

```
yyyy/MM/dd
```

My code:

```
string MyString: return the result of "SELECT MAX(Data_Column) FROM Table_Data T" (the last date registered in my BD)
```

MyString can be like:

`13/01/2013 00:00:00` or

`01/15/2013 00:00:00` or

`2013/02/30 00:00:00`, i dont know, it depends of language and short date format from each Operating System.
I need only the Date of MyString, the time info from MyString is not important
*/

DateTime dateIwillUse;

```
    if (DateTime.TryParse("20/01/2013", out dateIwillUse))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This System uses short Date in format: dd/MM/yyyy. Parsing in correct format to dateIwillUse:");
                dateIwillUse = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString.Substring(0, 10), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        //using the variable dateIwillUse with dateIwillUse.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), after correctly parsed
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse("01/20/2013", out dateIwillUse))
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("This system uses short date in format: MM/dd/yyyy.Parsing in correct format to dateIwillUse:");
                    dateIwillUse = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString.Substring(0, 10), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
                //using the variable dateIwillUse with dateIwillUse.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), after correctly parsed
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse("2013/01/20", out dateIwillUse))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This system uses short date in format: yyyy/MM/dd .Parsing in correct format to dateIwillUse:");
                dateIwillUse = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString.Substring(0, 10), "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);![enter image description here][2]
            //using the variable dateIwillUse with dateIwillUse.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), after correctly parsed
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse("01/20/2013", out dateIwillUse))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This system uses short date in format: MM/dd/yyyy .Parsing in correct format to dateIwillUse:");
                dateIwillUse = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString.Substring(0, 10), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                //using the variable dateIwillUse with dateIwillUse.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), after correctly parsed
            } else 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot determine the format. Is not MM/dd/yyyy, neither yyyy/MM/dd, or dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: You are having a localization issue, not an OS one. Are the dates being saved as strings in your db using different cultures? If so, there won't be much you can do.

Comment: why are you selecting the datetime out as some kind of string, then turning it back into a date?  is the data stored as a string?  How are you going to figure out which date 10/01/2013 is?  is that oct1 or jan10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you force a specific date format when you are retrieving your sql? This way your code will know the format your string will be in. There is no reason to write so many parsers.

http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Edit: added more info

Only your database knows the correct format of the date. If you try to use different parsers the date 01-05-2013 is January 5 2013 or May 1 2013 both are valid dates and will parse but they have very different meanings, be careful.

Comment: It Worked! 
i changed the select to:
"select MAX(to_char(DATE_COLUMN, 'yyyy-mm-dd')) LASTEST_DATE from DATE_TABLE T"
and just did this:
DateTime lastDate = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString.Substring(0, 10).Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
and worked! thx

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse has an overload that lets you parse based on the format of the date. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Parse2_Example